# Spring JPA : Validation failed for query for method public abstract method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Application is working fine when it has external `hibernate-core : 5.3.14.Final` added to it, along with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa : 2.4.3`.
When I try to remove the externally added `hibernate-core` it fails with following error while booting up:

```
...
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page
com.my_app.repository.MessageBZCRepository.searchByText(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
```

*NOTE*: Internally `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa : 2.4.3` has `Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final` added as a dependency. It shows so in logs and dependency tree.

#### JPA Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MessageBZCRepository extends JpaRepository<MessageBZCEntity, MessageBZCKey>, Searchable<MessageBZCEntity> {

    ...

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "messageEntity.applicationParameter")
    @Query("select x from MessageBZCEntity x where x.messageEntity.comments like ?1 or x.messageEntity.applicationParameter.parameterName like ?1 or x.zipCode like ?1 or x.userUpdated like ?1")
    Page<MessageBZCEntity> searchByText(String searchText, Pageable pageable);

    ...

}
```

I found out that removing `or x.messageEntity.applicationParameter.parameterName like ?1` from the above mentioned query eleminates the `IllegalArgumentException` from application boot log and application boots up properly.

#### Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MSG_Z")
@IdClass(MessageBZCKey.class)
public class MessageBZCEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "APPL_C", referencedColumnName = "APPL_C"
                    , nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "MSG_P_I", referencedColumnName = "MSG_P_I"
                    , nullable = false)

    })
    private MessageEntity messageEntity;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MSG")
@IdClass(MessageKey.class)
public class MessageEntity {

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "APPL_C", nullable = false)
    private ApplicationCode applicationCode;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MSG_P_I", nullable = false)
    private ApplicationParameterEntity applicationParameter;

    ...

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPL_PARM")
public class ApplicationParameterEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "APPL_PARM_I", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "PARM_TYPE_C", nullable = false)
    private ApplicationParameterType parameterType;

    @Column(name = "PARM_N", nullable = false)
    private String parameterName;

    ...
}
```

```
public class MessageKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ApplicationCode applicationCode;
    private Long applicationParameter;

}
```

I went through `hibernate-core` release notes, migration guides for hibernate-core:5.4.x but couldn't understand the root cause.

Need help in getting rid of this error. If anyone can route me towards the right direction, that would be certainly be helpful.

#### Update 1:

Adding raw console log output:

```
[TRACE] 2021-05-15 14:13:17,669 main org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [ABC]
[TRACE] 2021-05-15 14:13:17,669 main org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [XYZ]
[WARN] 2021-05-15 14:13:18,926 main org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - {} - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBZCServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageBZCRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBZCRepository' defined in com.my_app.repository.MessageBZCRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.my_app.repository.MessageBZCRepository.searchByText(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
[INFO] 2021-05-15 14:13:18,931 main org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - {} - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO] 2021-05-15 14:13:18,932 main com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - {} - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[INFO] 2021-05-15 14:13:19,268 main com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - {} - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
May 15, 2021 2:13:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

#### Update 2:

#### Update 2:

- Added MessageKey class
- I was able to isolate the relevant code in a new application with H2 database and found the complete stacktrace (`hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final` is being used with latest spring):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBZCRepository' defined in com.example.JPAIssueDemo.repository.MessageBZCRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.JPAIssueDemo.repository.MessageBZCRepository.searchByText(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.example.JPAIssueDemo.JpaIssueDemoApplication.main(JpaIssueDemoApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.JPAIssueDemo.repository.MessageBZCRepository.searchByText(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:216) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:303) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parameterName of: com.example.JPAIssueDemo.entity.sl.MessageBZCEntity [select x from com.example.JPAIssueDemo.entity.sl.MessageBZCEntity x where x.messageEntity.comments like ?1 or x.messageEntity.applicationParameter.parameterName like ?1 or x.zipCode like ?1 or x.userUpdated like ?1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parameterName of: com.example.JPAIssueDemo.entity.sl.MessageBZCEntity [select x from com.example.JPAIssueDemo.entity.sl.MessageBZCEntity x where x.messageEntity.comments like ?1 or x.messageEntity.applicationParameter.parameterName like ?1 or x.zipCode like ?1 or x.userUpdated like ?1]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parameterName of: com.example.JPAIssueDemo.entity.sl.MessageBZCEntity
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2038) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:412) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:520) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:695) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1055) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1308) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4778) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4388) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2166) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2119) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2116) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2116) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:832) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:626) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace. Also, why can't you update?

Comment: This is a WARN level output that is getting printed in the console before the application kills itself. I tried to change log level to TRACE/DEBUG for root/hibernate/spring boot but still had no success with the stack trace. Can you help me with a way to print that ?

Comment: How can this be a warning? In your question you were writing that the app fails to boot. Not sure which warning you mean.

Comment: Added raw console log output in the end for more info. Added few lines above and below it, if those could relate.

Comment: Why can't you just use the latest Hibernate version?

Comment: If by latest, you mean latest `5.x`, since I am planning to switch to `hibernate-core` that comes along with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, I tried to upgrade spring jpa to latest stable. It still failed with same error.

Comment: Also, found out changing this part of query : `or x.messageEntity.applicationParameter.parameterName like ?1` to something like `or x.messageEntity.field2 like ?1` solves the problem too. Is there any limit on the mapping from hibernate ? Or could this imply possible errors in the DB schema?

Comment: The query should be fine, but there must be some stack trace for the error you are seeing. Without this, it's impossible to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: This application is using Postgres DB for persistence. Will that be okay to try to reproduce the issue with H2? That shouldn't be a problem, right ?

Comment: Sure, that's fine.

Comment: can you share your MessageKey class? could you use a Long field instead of an ApplicationParameterEntity? so in MessageEntity i would remove @Id from the field ApplicationParameterEntity and i would add the new field `private Long applicationParameterId;` annotated `@Id` and `@Column(name = "MSG_P_I", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)`

Comment: @tremendous7 I have added `MessageKey` to the question body. Changing schema is a bit costly here. Since this is an RDBMS. I can't really do it unless I can prove that it is absolutely needed.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov As you had suggested, I isolated the relevant code and tried to reproduce the issue with H2 and latest Spring boot. Finally was able to see stack trace here for some reason, which wasn't the case earlier. I have added the complete stack trace in question body.

Comment: Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error with the below query.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Feedback f")
```

I changed the * with an alias and it worked

```
    @Query("SELECT f FROM Feedback f")
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following query

```
@Override
@Query("select x from MessageBZCEntity x join x.messageEntity as me join fetch me.applicationParamter as ap " +
        "where me.comments like ?1 or ap.parameterName like ?1 or x.zipCode like ?1 or x.userUpdated like ?1")
Page<MessageBZCEntity> searchByText(String searchText, Pageable pageable);
```